# Prevent TexWorks from saving after compiling

Tags: compiling, texworks

I'm going to tell you what I need/want (1) and what apparently TeXWorks does (2):

1. I need Texworks to compile files and not overwrite the .tex file. I don't mind if it creates another .dvi or .pdf files or if he changes them, but it would be cool if I don't have to worry that I can visualize a file without changing it.
2. If I open a file, and modify it, a `*` appears at the title window. That means the current file working has been modified from the original and there is something to save. If in this state your run the compiler, it shows the preview but the `*` is missing, meaning that it saved the file.

I also want to know this: If I modify a file and run the compiler, and if there are errors while compiling to be reported (not under/overfull box I don't care about that) but other errors, I skip errors with enter. I then close the file and compile again. Then not the same errors appear. Sometimes there are less errors. This behaviour puzzles me a lot. When pressing enter while compiling, it's possible that TeXWorks changes the file according to if you press enter while compiling?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with TeXworks, but you can probably convince other editors to do this (emacs is in my mind). The file has to be saved somewhere on disk for it to be processed by TeX. This would make a great feature request for TeXworks, though! (In the appropriate venue, of course.) Otherwise, the canonical answer to this is 'use version control'. TeXworks is not changing the file if you press enter (unless you save). At any rate, I doubt this race condition (as it's called) impacts the compilation process one iota.

Comment: It could be that there is a corrupt auxiliary file (`.aux`, `.toc`) etc. that gets rewritten during the compilation, so that the next time you compile the errors are gone. TeXworks wont change the`.tex`  file during compile because you choose to skip errors.

Comment: TeX cannot read files in the memory of TeX editors. Therefore TeX IDEs usually save the files before running the TeX compiler.

Comment: May be Gummi is for you. It can show a PDF preview every x seconds, or every x seconds o editor inactivity, or when you want, but it each compilation is made form a temporal swap file, so your .tex file is  modified only if you save the changes.  However, I don't believe that the risk of save undesired changes (that you can undo with Ctrl-Z) in TeXworks is worse that the risk lost the desired changes (**forever**).  Fortunately , in broken sessions Gummi can recover the swap file,  but not if you accidentally push "Discard" instead of "Save" buttons when closing Gummi.

Comment: @JosephWright In the [on-topic page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it says you can ask about "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.". Thanks!

Comment: @Santropedro Based on a parallel discussion, I've reopened

Comment: @JosephWright Well, you are a moderator with high rep, I trust in you!